# gnome icons messed up on top bar - show white blocks

Tags: 16.04, icons, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell

I am recently re-installed Ubutnu and followed the exact same steps of the previous install. After a successful install, I installed `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`. It was all fine till I noticed some icons were replaced by white blocks. ( Look at screenshot below )

[image: link to image]

Are there any known fixes to this issue?

Comment: Sure! I use Stack Overflow, so I am familiar with that system. In fact, I opened an AskUbuntu account for this very issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the current icon theme somehow got broke.

Open GNOME Tweak Tool and change the icon theme to one that works properly.

Comment: Thanks very much ( I'm sorry I couldn't show the image, not enough rep ). Very funny. I changed to from Paper to Suru then back to Paper, then the icon appeared.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem with Paper icon theme and 1.38 scaling factor.

Changing Gnome Tweak Tool -> Fonts -> Scaling factor solved it. The whole range between 1.35 to 1.40 was broken for wifi and battery, so I changed it to 1.41. Maybe the panel has some scaling bug or the icon set is suboptimal for this range.