# How can I fix garbled text and icons in gnome-shell title bar, task bar, and prompts without reseting the session?

Tags: gnome, unity, icons, indicator

`gnome-shell` crashed at some point and, upon reloading, all the text and almost all icons in the title bar, task bar, menus, and prompts are garbled.

I have a process that's been running for a week now; if it restarts, there's no way to recover the progress and I would have to start from scratch.  So, I'm looking for a way to resolve this without killing the processes I currently have running.

Thank you in advance!

[image: Screenshot of indicator panel]

[image: Screenshot of title bar, task bar, and menu]

[image: Screenshot of Unity search]

Comment: "Repairing" the font cache may help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224125/font-characters-displayed-as-squares-in-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: @vanadium - Upon your suggestion, I tried that. Unfortunately it did not fix the problem. It's worth noting that it isn't just a font issue -- the icons don't appear correctly either.

Comment: @Nmath - I've never experienced this before so I'm not sure how to reproduce it. `gnome-shell` is what crashed, so perhaps try running `sudo killall -9 gnome-shell` to see if that creates the same problem.  It's also possible that RAM might have been maxed or near maxed at the time.

Comment: @Nmath - Your comment is entirely incorrect & unhelpful. I provided a method of potentially reproducing the problem, though I can't be sure it will work - in 12 years of working in Linux, I've never experienced this. And I am absolutely willing to perform basic diagnostic steps, as demonstrated by my willingness to try vanadium's potential solution.  "Turning it off and on again" is not a diagnostic ("practice or techniques of diagnosis"), it's a potential solution. If you have an actual diagnostic you think I should run (e.g. I can check/share logs, if I know which ones), I'm happy to do so.

Comment: @vanadium - Correction. Your solution DID fix the menus and prompts! (Basically, anything with text.)  Thank you!  Icons are still garbled, though...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Font characters displayed as squares in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224125/font-characters-displayed-as-squares-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer: [gnome icons messed up on top bar - show white blocks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022360/gnome-icons-messed-up-on-top-bar-show-white-blocks)

In my case it started to happen (occasionally) after I replaced the monitor. Decreasing the font scale in Gnome Tweaks has fixed it:

[image]